# How do I order list by data from user's sub directory using firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to display users in the list according to the points they have in their own sub directory. In my app I create an user in the database according to its custom uid and make a directory with points according to which I want to sort the list. it looks as such:

```
users: {
    uid1: {
        name: something,
        game: {
            points: 10
        }
    },
    uid2: {
        name: something2,
        game: {
            points: 10
        }
    }
}
```

So first I'm gathering all uids and then use the snapshot to create path to the child which has a value that decides if the user participates in the game. Once it is evaluated I want to sort the list by points, but I cant find a way to do it. thought of using FirebaseUsers.orderByChild('game/points') however its not a valid argument.

```
FirebaseUsers.on('value', function(snapshot) {      
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var playerStatus = childSnapshot.child("game/player"),
            playerPoints = childSnapshot.child("game");         
        if(playerStatus.val() == true) {                
            allFirstNames += "<p>" + childSnapshot.val().firstname + "</p>";
            allLastNames += "<p>" + childSnapshot.val().lastname + "</p>";
            allPoints += "<p>" + playerPoints.val().points + "</p>";                                
        }
    });     
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only order items by a direct child property, not by a lower-level descendant. So you'll have to ensure that the value you want to order on is available at the user-level:

```
users: {
    uid1: {
        name: something,
        points: 10,
        game: {
        }
    },
    uid2: {
        name: something2,
        points: 10,
        game: {
        }
    }
}
```

If you happen to have multiple games under there, you'll most likely want to order on the maximum score that the player has. In that case, promote the highest of a player's scores to the user level:

```
users: {
    uid1: {
        name: something,
        max_points: 10,
        game: {
            points: 10
        }
    },
    uid2: {
        name: something2,
        max_points: 10,
        game: {
            points: 10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I thought I could work around it with some solution, but this will do the job